# Browser only prints what is displayed, not complete div content

Tags: css, printing, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap modals to display a report with the following css:

```
@media print {

    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #printSection, #printSection * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

It works, but when I need to print an extensive `div` content, the browser print preview only shows what the user can see, so that it cuts off content.

How to solve this?

Comment: Rewrite the body CSS in media print, make it visible in media print

Comment: I don't want to print the whole body, but a single div.
The following fiddle exemplifies the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/3zu008ch/75/

When you click on print (at the end of the list), you will see that when we are printing from a modal, only what you see is printed.